# What to do for this error- androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup?

Tags: java, android, androidx

Hope you all are fine in this pandemic. I am trying to create a sound recorder App in Android which would record and show the recorded files in another TAB. The list of recorded files can be played from the list. When I am playing the audio file from the list(screenshot), I am getting the following error:

```js
2020-11-12 10:54:21.816 4605-4605/com.icddrb.recordaudio E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.icddrb.recordaudio, PID: 4605
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #41: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSeekBar cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:884)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:886)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:846)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:522)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at com.icddrb.recordaudio.fragments.PlayBackFragment.onCreateDialog(PlayBackFragment.java:61)
        at androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment.onGetLayoutInflater(DialogFragment.java:380)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performGetLayoutInflater(Fragment.java:1412)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:881)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1238)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:439)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOps(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2079)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1869)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1824)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:165)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6375)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:802)
```

[image: screenshot of Soundrecorder App]

Here is my fragment_playback.xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/media_player_view"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:transitionName="open_mediaplayer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="File name.mp3"
                android:id="@+id/file_name_textview"/>

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/seekbar">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:text="00:00"
                        android:id="@+id/current_progress_tv"/>

                    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/fab_play"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_media_play"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:fab_shadow="false"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/file_length_text_view"
                        android:text="00:00"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>



            </SeekBar>



        </LinearLayout>



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my PlayBackFragment.java:

```js
package com.icddrb.recordaudio.fragments;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.graphics.ColorFilter;
import android.graphics.LightingColorFilter;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import com.icddrb.recordaudio.R;
import com.icddrb.recordaudio.model.RecodingItem;
import com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import butterknife.BindView;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

public class PlayBackFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @BindView(R.id.file_name_textview) TextView fileNameTV;
    @BindView(R.id.file_length_text_view) TextView fileLenghtTV;
    @BindView(R.id.seekbar) SeekBar seekBar;
    @BindView(R.id.current_progress_tv) TextView currentProgress;
    @BindView(R.id.fab_play) FloatingActionButton floatingActionButton;

    //SeekBar seekBar;

    private RecodingItem item;
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean isPlaying = false;

    long minutes =0;
    long seconds = 0;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        item = (RecodingItem) getArguments().getSerializable("item");
        minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(item.getLength());
        seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(item.getLength())- TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes);


    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_playback, null);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

        //seekBar = getView().findViewById(R.id.seekbar);


        seekbarValues();

        floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onPlay(isPlaying);
                isPlaying = !isPlaying;
            }
        });

        fileNameTV.setText(item.getName());
        fileLenghtTV.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds));

        builder.setView(view);
        dialog.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        return builder.create();

    }

    private void onPlay(boolean isPlaying) {

        if(!isPlaying){

            if(mediaPlayer != null){

                try {
                    startPlaying();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        } else{

            pausePlaying();
        }
    }

    private void pausePlaying() {

        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        handler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        mediaPlayer.pause();
    }

    private void startPlaying() throws IOException {

        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(item.getPath());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                stopPlaying();
            }
        });

        updateSeekbar();
        getActivity().getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    }

    private void seekbarValues() {

        ColorFilter colorFilter = new LightingColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary),
                getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

        seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(colorFilter);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if(mediaPlayer != null && fromUser){

                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
                    handler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);

                    long minutes= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
                    long seconds= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition()) -
                            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes);

                    currentProgress.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds));

                    updateSeekbar();


                } else if(mediaPlayer == null && fromUser){

                    try {
                        prepareMediaPlayerFromPoint(progress);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    updateSeekbar();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }

    private void prepareMediaPlayerFromPoint(int progress) throws IOException {

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(item.getPath());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                 stopPlaying();
            }
        });
    }

    private void stopPlaying() {

        floatingActionButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);
        handler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();

        mediaPlayer = null;

        seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getMax());

        isPlaying = !isPlaying;

        currentProgress.setText(fileLenghtTV.getText());
        seekBar.setProgress(seekBar.getMax());

    }

    private Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(mediaPlayer != null){
                int mCurrentPosition = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                seekBar.setProgress(mCurrentPosition);

                long minutes= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(mCurrentPosition);
                long seconds= TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(mCurrentPosition) -
                        TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(minutes);

                currentProgress.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds));
                updateSeekbar();
            }
        }
    };

    private void updateSeekbar() {

        handler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }
}
```

I am sharing my build.gradle file too:

```js
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.icddrb.recordaudio"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'


    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"

    implementation 'com.melnykov:floatingactionbutton:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'


    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'


    implementation "com.android.support:support-core-utils:29.0.0"








}
```

Thanks in advance for your kind assistance in this regard.

Comment: SeekBar can't contain views inside, it's not a ViewGroup, it extends View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your SeekBar have RelativeLayout.

So you have to set

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/media_player_view"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:transitionName="open_mediaplayer"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="7dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:text="File name.mp3"
                android:id="@+id/file_name_textview"/>

            <SeekBar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/seekbar"/>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width ="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height = "wrap_content">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:text="00:00"
                        android:id="@+id/current_progress_tv"/>

                    <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/fab_play"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_media_play"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:fab_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimary"
                        app:fab_shadow="false"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/file_length_text_view"
                        android:text="00:00"
                        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

                </RelativeLayout>


        </LinearLayout>



    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

like this.